# See streetview enabled streets without pegman

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I don't want to use streetview, I just want to see what streets allow it and capture a graphic (so as to identify gated neighborhoods where the cars could not get in.) Of course one can drag out the pegman and do a screen capture (or several if one wants to stitch them together). One can use that method to (w/o the pegman) to capture maps (w/o highlighting s/v/e streets) HOWEVER there are much [nicer ways](http://www.codres.de/google-map-saver/gms-download) to get an 8000 x 8000 pixel map (for example).

> Question: Is there same way to leave the display of streetview enabled streets on without hovering the pegman?)

I once had this happen while I was using Gmaps(maybe due to where I dropped the man) but have never replicated it.